# Django Session Middleware causing Exceptions

Tags: python, django

I cannot figure out what is going on here. I have a session that is stored when a user accesses a url like: website.com/client, where the client is the client using the system. This is stored in the session using `django.contrib.sessions`

Here is my middleware declaration:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    # must be before session middleware
    'utils.middleware.routers.ClientDatabaseRouterMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

    # custom middleware
    # 'utils.middleware.CookieMiddleware.CookieMiddleware',
    # 'utils.middleware.ExtendSession.ExtendSessionMiddleware',
    'utils.middleware.UniversalDataMiddleware.UniversalDataMiddleware',
    'apps.fort.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
    'utils.middleware.TimezonesMiddleware.TimezonesMiddleware',
    'utils.middleware.SessionMiddleware.SessionMiddleware',  # maybe rewrite this?
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',           # auto adds user who makes change
    # 'utils.middleware.Profilers.ProfileMiddleware',
    # anything under this is excluded when decorator @property_not_important is called
    'utils.middleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware.ExcludePropertyMiddleware',
    # allow exclusion
    'utils.middleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware.CheckPropertyMiddleware',
    # 'utils.middleware.ExcludeMiddleware.ExcludeMiddleware',
]
```

It is also in INSTALLED_APPS.

My problem is when I git the `client url` django stores the session, but when I go back to the main site the session lookup causes a 500 error because the sessions are stored in each client DB... how can I fix this?

If I manually remove the `sessionid` session generated by django in my browser, my site loads without 500, so I am not sure how to remove it.

Comment: What is the exact error? What is the code writing and reading from session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as I stated was that my `django_sessions` table was stored in a different DB than my default DB as I base this off of `client_url` to dictate which version of the system being used (i.e. for which client).

To fix this I had to slightly alter the session middleware provided by Django: `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` so I could check the request for the `client_url` variable because that was the only way I was getting my session stored or updated.

Here is the revised code I used in place of: `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`

```
import time
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.base import UpdateError
from django.contrib.sessions.exceptions import SessionInterrupted
from django.urls import resolve
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
from django.utils.http import http_date


class SessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    pass
    # RemovedInDjango40Warning: when the deprecation ends, replace with:
    #   def __init__(self, get_response):
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        super().__init__(get_response)
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        self.SessionStore = engine.SessionStore

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
        # print(request.path, resolve(request.path_info).kwargs)

        if 'client_url' in resolve(request.path_info).kwargs:
            print('client url found')
            request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)
            # print(self.SessionStore(session_key), self.SessionStore(session_key).__dict__)
        else:
            # this is an error because the db cannot be found without client_url,
            # but we need to assign session or auth does not work
            print('session eluded...')
            request.session = {}

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        If request.session was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
        session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie or delete
        the session cookie if the session has been emptied.
        """
        try:
            accessed = request.session.accessed
            modified = request.session.modified
            empty = request.session.is_empty()
        except AttributeError:
            return response
        # First check if we need to delete this cookie.
        # The session should be deleted only if the session is entirely empty.
        if settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME in request.COOKIES and empty:
            response.delete_cookie(
                settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                samesite=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )
            patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
        else:
            if accessed:
                patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
            if (modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) and not empty:
                if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
                    max_age = None
                    expires = None
                else:
                    max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
                    expires_time = time.time() + max_age
                    expires = http_date(expires_time)
                # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
                # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
                if response.status_code != 500:
                    try:
                        request.session.save()
                    except UpdateError:
                        raise SessionInterrupted(
                            "The request's session was deleted before the "
                            "request completed. The user may have logged "
                            "out in a concurrent request, for example."
                        )
                    response.set_cookie(
                        settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                        request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                        expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                        path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                        secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                        httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None,
                        samesite=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
                    )
        return response
```